# preactions":"truncate table is not working in glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm using aws glue to transform data from CSV to RDS (mysql). In the final step, I implement this statement

```
datasink = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame
  .from_jdbc_conf(
    frame = selectfields, 
    catalog_connection = "rds_conn",
    connection_options = {"preactions":"truncate table dim_customer_scd;","dbtable": "dim_customer_scd", "database": "sales"},
    transformation_ctx = "datasink")
```

What I expect is that I want to truncate the table (dim_customer_scd) before inserting a dynamic frame (selectfields) to it. Unfortunately, new data is inserted correctly but old data is still there (not deleted)
I doubt that "preactions":"truncate table dim_customer_scd" is not working. Does anyone have ideas about it? Thank very much